# Trying to run a "WHERE IS NOT NULL" query in SQL but receiving a error?

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm trying to run this command in pg-promise for node/express:

```
const condition = pgp.as.format(" WHERE value IS NOT null", values);
const query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs) + condition;
```

Which translates to this:

```
INSERT INTO "formquestionresponse"("attrib_id","value","response_id") VALUES(63,'Philadelphia Flyers','135'),(64,'Test','135'),(68,null,'135'),(77,null,'135') WHERE value IS NOT null
```

But I am getting a SQL error 16:03:46 error: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix that...am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just trying to get SQL to insert when the "value" isn't null ,, so in that example it should insert the first 2 sets of VALUES but not the last two

Comment: That is nonsensical.  If you are including data in `Values` you want to `INSERT` it. Please spend some time here [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Comment: You need to do an INSERT with subquery to have a WHERE clause.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like this: ```INSERT INTO "formquestionresponse"("attrib_id","value","response_id") 
select a,value,c from
(values (63,'Philadelphia Flyers','135'),(64,'Test','135'),(68,null,'135'),(77,null,'135')) t(a,value,c) WHERE value IS NOT null```

Comment: Do not execute this statement from your application side if the value is null. Your database will be happy with it (no network communication, parsing, execution at all).

Comment: Thanks for the help all. The insert statement and values is dynamically generated, so that's why I thought you could do a where not null. Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT ... VALUES ...` statements cannot have `WHERE` clauses.

If you don't want to insert certain tuples with an `INSERT ... VALUES ...` statement, don't list them in the `VALUES` clause.

What you could do is and `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM (VALUES ...) ...` statement:

```
INSERT INTO formquestionresponse
            (attrib_id,
             value,
             response_id)
            SELECT attrib_id,
                   value,
                   response_id
                   FROM (VALUES (63,
                                 'Philadelphia Flyers',
                                 '135'),
                                (64,
                                 'Test',
                                 '135'),
                                (68,
                                 NULL,
                                 '135'),
                                (77,
                                 NULL,
                                 '135') v (attrib_id,
                                           value,
                                           response_id)
                   WHERE value IS NOT NULL;
```

But I don't think this is the easier or in any way better option.